# $E[|X|]$ for gamma distributed random variable $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be Gamma distributed with density $$f_\theta(x)=\frac{\theta^3}{2}x^2e^{-\theta x},\quad\theta\in(0,\infty).$$

Now I want to calculate $E[|X|]$, i.e.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|x|\frac{\theta^3}{2}x^2e^{-\theta x}dx,$$

but I do not really know how. In the end I just want to know if it is $<\infty$. Is there an easy argument?

Comment: Hmm, isn't the Gamma density only nonzero for $x\geq 0$? So $|x|=x$, right? And so $E[|X|]=E[X]$ since $X\geq 0$ if $X$ is Gamma-distributed?

Comment: Ah, yes, this information was missing. Thank you!